# Symfony Validator: How to validate deeply nested data using the XML notation?

Tags: php, symfony, validation

How can I describe the constraints for a nested collection of data using the Symfony validators XML notation for the rules?

I've tried to use the `all` and `collection` constraints and combine them somehow, but I can't get the offers validated. How can I validate the 2nd or even deeper data?

Test code:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

$validatorBuilder = Validation::createValidatorBuilder();
$validator = $validatorBuilder->enableAnnotationMapping()
    ->addXmlMapping('validation.xml')
    ->getValidator();

$transfer = new \Generated\Shared\Transfer\ProductConcreteTransfer();
$transfer->fromArray([
    'numberOfOffers' => 0,
    'defaultPrice' => null,
    'offers' => [
        [
            'idProductOffer' => 1,
            'merchantName' => null,
        ],
        [
            'idProductOffer' => 1,
            'merchantName' => null,
        ]
    ]
]);

$result = $validator->validate($transfer);

if ($result->count() > 0) {
    echo "Validation failed. Found " . $result->count() . " violation(s):\n";

    foreach ($result as $violation) {
        echo sprintf(
            "Property: %s | Constraint: %s | Message: %s\n",
            $violation->getPropertyPath(),
            get_class($violation->getConstraint()),
            $violation->getMessage()
        );
    }
} else {
    echo "Validation passed. No violations found.\n";
}
```

The `validation.xml` file:

```
<constraint-mapping xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping https://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping/constraint-mapping-1.0.xsd">

    <class name="Generated\Shared\Transfer\ProductConcreteTransfer">
        <property name="abstractSku">
            <constraint name="Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank"/>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultPrice">
            <constraint name="Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank"/>
        </property>
        <property name="numberOfOffers">
            <constraint name="Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank"/>
            <constraint name="Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length">
                <option name="min">1</option>
                <option name="max">50</option>
            </constraint>
        </property>
        <property name="offers">
            <!-- How do I validate each entity in the collection? -->
        </property>
    </class>
</constraint-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the [`Valid`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html) constraint should help you.

> This constraint is used to enable validation on objects that are embedded as properties on an object being validated. This allows you to validate an object and all sub-objects associated with it.